# How to define a path section in custom actions of $resource?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to specify the path of a custom $resource action ?

I would like to write something like:

```
angular.module('MyServices', [ 'ngResource' ]).factory('User', [ '$resource', ($resource)->
  $resource('/users', {}, {
    names: { path: '/names', method: 'GET', isArray: true }
  })
])
```

So I can use it like:

```
User.names() # GET /users/names
```

Comment: The accepted answer is long-obsolete; not only is the feature it talks about merged in, but there are [more straightforward alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20022017/1709587).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not directly supported in the current version of AngularJS but there is a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2054) open so there is chance that it will be supported in the near future.

Till then you've got 3 options:

1) Play with variables in the path:

```
$resource('/users/:names', {}, {
    names: { params: {names: 'names'}, method: 'GET', isArray: true }
  })
```

2) Use the [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) instead

3) Try the code from the mentioned PR on the monkey-patched version of AngularJS

Comment: Now there is a `url` property in Angular 1.2 - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20022017/2583484

Answer (score 6):

Check the logs in this [working Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/83WiADg9JKJjzLpGHarH/preview) (excerpt):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource'])
  .controller('MyController', 
    function($scope, $resource) {
      var User = $resource(
        '/users/:action',
        {},
        {
          names:{
            method:'GET', 
            params:{action:'names'}
          }
        }
      );

      $scope.users = User.get();
      $scope.names = User.names();
    }  
  );
```

Answer (score 5):

A less eloquent, but equally effective method:

```
var resourceUrl =  '/users';
return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
    names: { path: resourceUrl + '/names', method: 'GET', isArray: true }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

From Angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource
you can specify 'url' for your custom action which will override the previous one.

```
angular.module('MyServices', ['ngResource']).factory('User', ['$resource', ($resource)-> $resource('/users', {}, {
names: { url: '/users/names', method: 'GET', isArray: true }
})])
```

It works in my project using angular 1.3.10!

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks!