# How can I create a service that returns data using $resource depending on parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a service which calls the backend depending on parameters. This code does not work, but I hope it shows what I would like to achieve:

```
myproject.factory('Item', function($resource) {
    if (@id !== undefined)
        return $resource('/resource/item/:id/item.json', {id: '@id'});
    else if (@userid !== undefined)
        return $resource('/resource/user/:userid/items.json', {userid: '@userid'});
});
```

Basically the first option only returns one item by its id, the second option returns the several items by userid.

I would then like to be able to call that service like this:

```
$scope.item = Item.get({id: id}, function() {...}
```

or

```
$scope.items = Item.query({userid: userid}, function() {...}
```

What is the best way to achieve something like that? Do I need to create separate services for everything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can override the default URL using custom `actions` parameter: [see $resource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

I mean something like this:

```
$resource('/resource/item/:id/item.json', {}, {
    query: {
        url: '/resource/user/:userid/items.json',
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true
    }
});
```

Now `.get()` and other requests will use the default URL, while `.query()` should use custom URL.

Note that the `url` property is new in Angular 1.2 (now stable release).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use querystring parameters instead?

However, you have to think of the next person who comes to support it, or want to make updates to it, whether that is a future you or someone else. Making it overly generic and complicated doesn't help anyone. It quickly becomes difficult to build and then maintain.

Your entities are `user` and `item`, so best practice would be to treat them as separate resources your app can make use of.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would you suggest to find all items for one user then? Will I need to create a service "ItemsByUser"?

Comment: I would suggest a user *has* items, so your URL would look something like this: `/resource/user/:userId/items/` then if you want a particular item you could have `/resource/user/:userId/items/:itemId`.

Comment: Yep, that is how I do it at the moment. To accomplish the two different cases I have two different services (one called "Items" which takes the itemid, another one called "ItemsByUser" which takes the userid and returns the user items. The two services call the resource pathes similar to how you suggested. This works fine, however I thought there might be a way to combine the two of them in one service. If I have to continue creating a new service for each path I need to call there will be a lot of services in the end...

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a new service for each path, simply handle null for `itemId` on your server. If `itemId` is null send to the client all the user's items. If an `itemId` is present return the single item back to the client