# AngularJS - Detailed explanation on $resource actions

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to understand how to use $resource **actions** argument.

Can you please explain with example about [$resource **actions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage) argument especially how "timeout" works etc.

Comment: please check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: exaple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076696/how-to-define-a-path-section-in-custom-actions-of-resource

Comment: problem with soluation full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928741/how-to-use-angularjs-resource-custom-actions